# random.nextDouble creates the same sequence in a for block

Tags: java, random

I have the following code to create a random series of a numbers from 0 to a given amount.

```
ArrayList<Integer> places = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUMBER; cnt++) {
    int place = (int)(random.nextDouble()*places.size());
    places.add(place , new Integer(cnt));
}
```

I use this code in a method and then I run this method for about 1000 times for statistics purposes. 
My problem is that created series is the same for all of the 1000 time.
Every time that I run the sequence is different, but same for all of the for values.
What should I do? Is there a method like srand() in C++?

Comment: How are you creating the `Random` object?  Your sample is incomplete.

Comment: This question is un-clear, do you want to guarantee different values everything or do you want to guarantee the same "random" values every time? Show how you are creating the `random` instance as well.

Comment: "Every time that I run the sequence is different, but same for all of the for values." what does this mean?

Comment: How you seeding that random number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm seems flawed if you are trying to generate an array with numbers `0 ... NUMBER-1` in random order. Consider:

```
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
...
ArrayList<Integer> places = new ArrayList<Integer>(NUMBER);
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER; ++i) {
  places.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(places, rnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use you use Math.random(). It will return a double from 0.0 to 1.0 exclusively. So you can replace the 2 lines inside the for loop with this:

```
places.add((int)(Math.random() * places.size()),cnt);
//you don't have to do "new   Integer(cnt)" because of Java's auto-boxing feature
```